# cURL file download speed inconsistent. Slow download roughly happens once per 10 attempts

Tags: curl, libcurl

I grabbed latest curl v7.53.1 from cURL's website.
I built the cURL (STATIC linking) in windows x86 and leave all options as default, i.e. ENABLE_SSPI, ENABLE_IPV6, ENABLE_IDN, ENABLE_WINSSL.

After the build finishes and curl.exe generated, I ran the command "curl.exe -O http://mydownloadfile.xxx". The download ended with success but if I ran this cmd couple of times, it shows that there are cases that the download speed is extremely slow (500K while the regular speed is ~25M). The ratio of reproducing this slowness is 1/10 roughly. I'm sure my network condition is very stable and fast.

Here is the screenshot from my tests:
[Slow file download using cURL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y349E.png)

This issue can also be found at android and iOS. So I think it's not platform specific. Anyone has experienced the same problem? Any idea if that could be a cURL bug? I'm on curl v7.53.1 but I can also see the issue on curl 7.19.x.

EDIT:
It turns out an issue from the cloud that we using. Not a fault of cURL at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check another website to see what is the speed ?
Maybe it can be from website, they might be slowing down you after a couple try.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I've tried to download on another site and it's working normally. Seems like we got problem on the cloud we using.